# Bitnami Lime Survey and MS SQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bitnami, limesurvey

I'm trying to setup a Bitnami Limesurvey stack on my local and I've seen that it is running MySQL as its default DB.

Question is Can I migrate this into MS SQL Database?

Please feel free to comment, will be pretty much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Limesurvey supports multiple Databases.
https://manual.limesurvey.org/Installation#Make_sure_you_can_use_LimeSurvey_on_your_website

I believe you can migrate the DB and then just point the DB config to the new DB.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to export the surveys as survey archives (.lsa and .lss), install a new LimeSurvey version on MSSQL and import the archives using LimeSurvey.
But that depends on how many surveys you have in your old installation.